# AS3 > Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event

Tags: actionscript-3, events, box2d

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.

private function contactListener(e:Event)
    {
        if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox))
        {
            // Won.
            trace ('You won!');
        }
    }
```

Full Code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.actionsnippet.qbox.QuickContacts;

[SWF(width = 600, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  

public class LuckyHit extends MovieClip {

    public var sim:QuickBox2D;
    var winBox:QuickObject;
    var looseBox:QuickObject;
    var gameBall:QuickObject;
    var simContacts:QuickContacts;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function LuckyHit()
    {
        sim = new QuickBox2D(this);
        simContacts = sim.addContactListener();
        simContacts.addEventListener(QuickContacts.ADD, contactListener);
        //sim.createStageWalls();
        winBox = sim.addBox({x:5,y:600/30, width:300/30, height:10/30, density:0});
        looseBox = sim.addBox({x:15,y:600/30, width:300/30, height:10/30, density:0});



        // make obstacles 
        for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.stageWidth/50); i++){ 
        //End
             sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:16, radius:0.1, density:0});
             sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:15, radius:0.1, density:0});

        //Mid End

              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:14, radius:0.1, density:0});
              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:13, radius:0.1, density:0});
              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:12, radius:0.1, density:0});
              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:11, radius:0.1, density:0});
              sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:10, radius:0.1, density:0});


        //Middle Start
             sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:09, radius:0.1, density:0});
             sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:08, radius:0.1, density:0});
             sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:07, radius:0.1, density:0});
             sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:06, radius:0.1, density:0});

        }

        sim.start();


        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
    }

    /**
     * ..
     * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
     */

    private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        gameBall = sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(1), radius:0.25, density:5});


    }

    private function contactListener(e:Event)
    {
        if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox))
        {
            // Won.
            trace ('You won!');
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the `Event` class:

```
import flash.events.Event;
```

Comment: Hmm. Got a new error > `Incorrent number of arguments. Expected 2` 

at

`if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox))`

Comment: This means that the `isCurrentContact()` function on the `QuickContacts` object requires two arguments; you are only passing one argument. Check the docs for `QuickContacts`. Now accept my answer ! :)

Comment: You solved that question as well, this is the correct statement: `(simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox,gameBall))`